# Pass value from activity to CustomDialog class

Tags: android, dialog, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

Hi i want to pass a value "username" which i saved through SharedPreferences in my activity to a EditText in a CustomDialog class.
Meaning i want to use `EditText.settext (username)` in my CustomDialog class.
Can somebody help me to achieve this?

Thank you.

SharedPreference code in Main activity:

```
public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
   ...

@Override     
protected void onPause() { 
    super.onPause(); 
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
    e.putString(USERNM, username);
    e.commit();
}
}
```

Now i want to set the value "USERNM" to the EditText in my CustomDialog class:

```
public class MyCustomForm extends Dialog {

  public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    ...
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(com.sencide.R.layout.inlogdialog);
        EditText userTest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);

        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", this.MODE_PRIVATE); // does not work
        String text = mPrefs.getString("USERNM", ""); 
        userTest.setText(text);
  }
}
```

CustomDialog:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
...

public class MyCustomForm extends Dialog {

String mTextChange;
public SharedPreferences mPrefs;


public interface ReadyListener {
    public void ready(String user, String pass, boolean save);
}

private String usernm;
private String passwd;
private ReadyListener readyListener;


public MyCustomForm(Context context, String user, String pass, ReadyListener readyListener) {
    super(context);
    this.usernm = user;
    this.passwd = pass;
    this.readyListener = readyListener;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(com.sencide.R.layout.inlogdialog);
    setTitle("Login:");
    EditText userTest = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    //mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //String text = mPrefs.getString("USERNM", "");
    userTest.setText();

    Button buttonConfrim = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
    buttonConfrim.setOnClickListener(new OKListener());

    Button buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new CancelListener());


}


private class OKListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpass);
        CheckBox saveuser = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.saveuser);

        readyListener.ready(user.getText().toString(),pass.getText().toString(), saveuser.isChecked());

        MyCustomForm.this.dismiss();
    }
}


private class CancelListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyCustomForm.this.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Edit, in my main activity:

```
public void createDialog(Context context) { 
     SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("mPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
     String user = prefs.getString("USERNM", ""); 
        new MyCustomForm(context, user, user, null); // where the class that is calling this is aa OnTextChangeListener 
    }
```

This is how i show the Dialog:

```
public void getLoginData() throws Exception {

    if (checkInternetConnection() == true){
        MyCustomForm dialog = new MyCustomForm (this, "", "", new OnReadyListener());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.inlogdialog);
        dialog.show();       
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you post the exception log and clearly state where the issue is?

Comment: Hi Jack,
The problem is that the value gets saved, that`s ok, but i do not know how to pass it through SharedPreferences to a class.
From activity to activity i could use Intent but not from an activity to a class.
I already have problems creating the SharedPreferences code in the Dialog class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [not recommended](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) to pass context around (and by extension views). I would suggest creating a listener for your dialog, maybe something like an `OnTextChangedListener#onChange(String)`.

Create the listener in your activity and pass it to your dialog. Then when the dialog is done, call the listeners `onChange(String)` method which will be set to fire an event to a UI thread handler to update the edit text. Conversely, you could just pass the handler.

```
public class MyDialog exteds Dialog implements Dialog.OnClickListener {
    OnTextChangeListener mListener;
    String mTextChange;

    public MyDialog(OnTextChangeListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        // set up your stuff
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    ...

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Do what ever you need to do to get set mTextChange
        mListener.onChange(mTextChange);
    }

    public static interface OnTextChangeListener {
        void onChange(String textChange);
}
```

Here is how you pass it:

```
 public void createDialog(Context context) {
     SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     String user = prefs.getString("what_ever_string_you_want", "fall_back_user_name");
        new MyDialog(user, this); // where the class that is calling this is aa OnTextChangeListener
    }
```

Comment: Hi AedonEtLIRA,
Thank you for answering i already made a listner in the activity, see edited code.
Could you help me with some example code to pass the username value saved with the SharedPreferences  to the Dialog.class?
I am quit new to Android.

Comment: @Lars That is, simply, what I would do.

Comment: Hmmm, i can`t get it done.
Can this not be done through SharedPreferences?, as i also saved the value through SharedPreferences.
If not thx for your help and efforts anyway.

Comment: I do not know how to pass the saved USERNM value fro SharedPreferences to the CustomDialog, i will post the whole code from the CustomDialog, maybe you see a way?

Comment: Hmmm ok, thx for the code but the edittext stays empty after i saved the value.
See my edited code.

Comment: It's probably staying empty because you don't have a value saved under that key. Change the default set from "" to "Nothing is here" to test my theory.

Comment: Did that, now i am getting a NullPointer Exception on line 512:
Editor e = mPrefs.edit(); <----

Comment: Is mPrefs set to anything before you call it? The code you have posted indicates no.

Comment: It went fine after i added the code, now i do not know were to search anymore.
Think i am too tired after a hard week of work, i am throwing the towl.
I did not know that it was soo hard to put a saved value from an activity to a class.
Anyhow i very much appreciate youre help AedonEtLIRA, thx again for youre efforts.

Comment: Hi AedonEtLIRA,
Just wanted to let you know that i fixed as you pushed me in the right direction, so i`ll accept your answer.
Thx again.